# Python asyncio call subprocess in correct order and stop tasks on condition

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to execute a subprocess using asyncio.create_subprocess_exec()
several times and stop the other running tasks when a certain condition is met
(In this case when the correct number 123 is entered).

However the tasks are not executed in the correct order, which is important for me
since i want to benchmark it, so i can compare the results to another subprocess.

I'm not sure if an asyncio.Event would help, because I would still need
to have a way to stop the other running tasks as soon as the correct number
was entered and the correct success message returned, so I can benchmark it.

Further more I encountered an error "ValueError: I/O operation on closed pipe"
when I used asyncio.run(main(130)) with an higher number like 240 and so.

This is my Python code to benchmark the subprocesses:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def call_subprocess(num: int):

    cmd_go = "guess_the_number_go.exe"
    # cmd_c = "guess_the_number_c.exe"
    process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
        cmd_go,
        stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)

    user_input = f"{num}\n".encode('utf-8') # encode to bytes
    process.stdin.write(user_input)
    bytes_reply, trash = await process.communicate()
    str_data = bytes_reply.decode("utf-8")
    cleaned_reply = str_data.strip("\n").strip("\r").split("\n")[-1]

    BAD_MESSAGE = "Sorry but your number is wrong, please try again."

    if cleaned_reply == BAD_MESSAGE:
        print(f"You entered {num}, it is the wrong number please try again!")
        print("---------------------------------------------------------")

    else:
        print(f"\nGreat your guess was right! The correct number is: {num}\n")
        print("\n*********************************************************")

        # cancel all the other tasks, since we have found the correct number
        for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks():
            task.cancel()

async def main(number: int):
    start_time = time.time()
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(call_subprocess(i)) for i in range(number)]

    try:
        _ = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Remaining tasks were cancelled!")

    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print("--------------------------------------------------")
    print(f"Execution took {round(elapsed_time, 2)} seconds.")

asyncio.run(main(130))
```

The Unordered output I get and execution of the tasks is like this:

> ### You entered 0, it is the wrong number please try again!
>
> ### You entered 4, it is the wrong number please try again!
>
> ### You entered 2, it is the wrong number please try again!
>
> ### ...
>
> ### You entered 124, it is the wrong number please try again!
>
> ### Great your guess was right! The correct number is: 123

### My Expected output though should look like that:

> ### You entered 0, it is the wrong number please try again!
>
> ### You entered 1, it is the wrong number please try again!
>
> ### You entered 2, it is the wrong number please try again!
>
> ### ...
>
> ### You entered 122, it is the wrong number please try again!
>
> ### Great your guess was right! The correct number is: 123

To better follow along, i have also added the code listings
for the two subprocesses I want to benchmark.

Simply put the user enters a number on the console and
it is compared with the secret number 123 and depending
on a success or try again message is printed out.

Go code: guess_the_number.go

```
package main
// compile with: >go build guess_the_number.go
import "fmt"

func main() {
    var secretNumber = 123
    var userInput int

    fmt.Printf("Please input a number: ")
    _, err := fmt.Scanf("%d", &userInput)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Something went wrong, only input numbers!")
        panic("Closing program!")
    }
    fmt.Printf("Your chosen number was: %d\n", userInput)

    if (userInput == secretNumber) {
        fmt.Printf("Congratulation you guessed the correct number!\n")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Sorry but your number is wrong, please try again.\n")
    }
}
```

C code: guess_the_number.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
// compile with: >gcc -o guess_the_number_c.exe guess_the_number.c
int main(void)
{
    int secretNumber = 123;
    int userInput;

    printf( "Please input a number: ");
    scanf("%i", &userInput);
    printf("Your entered number was: %i\n", userInput);
    if (userInput == secretNumber)
    {
        printf("Congratulation you guessed the correct number!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Sorry but your number is wrong, please try again.\n");
    };
    return (0);
}
```

I'm glad about any help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up with a ThreadPoolExecutor solution, because i think it is better suited for my usecase.

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import subprocess
import time

def bruteforce_input(args: list):
    input_number = args[0]
    e = args[1] # asyncio.Event to notify other threads when number was found

    # if event is true, correct number was already found, return immediately
    if e.is_set():
        return

    go_executable = "guess_the_number_go.exe"
    # c_executable = "guess_the_number_c.exe"
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        go_executable, 
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    user_input = f"{input_number}\n".encode('utf-8')
    process.stdin.write(user_input)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

    if stderr:
        print(f"Error occured: {stderr}")
        return

    str_data = stdout.decode("utf-8")
    cleaned_reply = str_data.strip("\n").strip("\r").split("\n")[-1]
    BAD_MESSAGE = "Sorry but your number is wrong, please try again."

    if cleaned_reply == BAD_MESSAGE:
        return {False: input_number}

    else:
        e.set() # set event flag to true, since correct number was found
        return {True: input_number}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    event = asyncio.Event()
    input_numbers = [[i, event] for i in range(150)]

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for reply in executor.map(bruteforce_input, input_numbers):
            if reply and reply.get(True):
                print("***********************************************\n\n")
                print(f"You're right! Correct number is: {reply[True]}\n\n")
                print("***********************************************\n")

            elif reply and reply.get(False):
                print(f"{reply[False]} is the wrong number please try again!")
                print("\n-----------------------------------------------\n")

    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Execution time: {round(elapsed_time, 2)} seconds.")
```

Now my output is as I wanted to have it and looks like that:

```
...
...
...
-----------------------------------------------
120 is the wrong number please try again!
-----------------------------------------------
121 is the wrong number please try again!
-----------------------------------------------
122 is the wrong number please try again!
-----------------------------------------------
***********************************************

You're right! Correct number is: 123

***********************************************
124 is the wrong number please try again!
-----------------------------------------------
125 is the wrong number please try again!
-----------------------------------------------
126 is the wrong number please try again!
-----------------------------------------------
127 is the wrong number please try again!
-----------------------------------------------
128 is the wrong number please try again!
-----------------------------------------------
129 is the wrong number please try again!
-----------------------------------------------
130 is the wrong number please try again!
-----------------------------------------------
131 is the wrong number please try again!
-----------------------------------------------
Execution time: 0.92 seconds.
```

I still wonder why after the "You're right! Correct number is: 123"
message the other failure messages are still printed,
I assume this happens because several workers are started
at once, depending of the max_workers argument.

max_workers argument of ThreadPoolExecutor() is set by default to: os.cpu_count() + 4 => 8 in my case.

So the 8 started workers finish their work before the next ones are started and are informed that asyncio.Event was set to true and correct number was found, could this be the possible reason?